# Find name of differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'd found earlier a function that obtain differential equations type (famous name such Bernoulli, Riccati,...) but I forgot function name!

this page show names available in wolfram mathematica.

[name of equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToODEs.html)

Comment: Are you looking for a function that maps differential equations  (expressed in Mathematica) to the name of their class?

Comment: as far as I know, Mathematica does not have such a function. You _might_ be thinking of Maple's `DEtools:-odeadvisor` which gives the name/type of an ode?

Comment: @MNazaari try [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*(diff(y(x),+x))%2Ba*y(x)%5E2-y(x)%2Bb*x%5E2)

Comment: Thank you Nasser, that was I needed exactly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a Mathematica issue.

Comment: I think that this is a relevant question. There is a function in Mathematica that describes what the OP has asked and if you can't recall its name it is darn hard to find. I believe the function in question is called `FormulaData`.